# Problem with Django foreign key field with to_field attribute

Tags: python, django, database

I have my model of User object which is related to Group object (example). So user has something like:

```
group_name = models.ForeignKey(Group, to_field="group_name", ...)
```

(of course the `group_name` is defined as unique as it's not a primary key in Group object)

But when I'm trying to change the `group_name` value for some Group object (regardless it's via Admin interface or within the code by updating the selected object) it raises the `Integrity error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

I know there is a mandatory parameter `on_delete` for the foreign key filed but I've tried all potential pre-defined values (`models.SET_DEFAULT`, `models.CASCADE`, etc.) but without any change.

It seems to me I need something what to do `on_update`, but that's not possible attribute ;-)

Here is some code samples

```
class Group(models.Model):  
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='teams', blank=True)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='managed_teams')
    # name is short because MySQL does not allow unique char fields to be long
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$')])


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="username", blank=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, to_field="name", default="Platform Validation and Testing")
```

And what I simply do in code (pre-condition is that I have already some objects stored in DB with User - Group relation):

```
from myapp.models import Group
group = Group.objects.all()[0]
group.name = "Some new cool name"
group.save()
```

and here is the `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

As I mentioned the same happens if I change the Group name field within Admin interface of Django.

Comment: can you show how you are updating value from code. This is very little code to understand where actual problem lies and also full Model definition is needed to see what is going on in your database.

Comment: Why do you need to use `to_field` here? Is there some reason you couldn't just have it point to the PK?

Comment: Sure I can use native approach with PK but don't won't to re-write my app if this approach should work as well (per Django official documentation)

Comment: Where is group_name field in your group model? @AKX

Comment: @AKX - sorry - I created semi-real example ;-) code updated now.

Comment: Right, so the actual point is you want your users to belong to some "known" group by default without having to know their IDs in advance?

Comment: Yes, primarily I needed to show Users group name, so instead of obtaining group name via it's ID I found the `to_field` as kind of shortcut, but now I see it has some limitations (per the answer provided)

Answer (score 1):

When you change the group name, the user which points to the original group name is suddenly pointing to a non-existing group. So you can't do that without first checking if any user is pointing to it. Change your code to first check all users pointing to your group, unset the fk, and then either reset it to the new group_name or leave it unset.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I thought it is the issue but I supposed Django has some mechanism how to do this automatically (I was thinking about that `on_update` way) - anyway I'll probably redesign my application to use Group PK so the name change won't affect me than.